# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR from multiple websites on multiple browsers and devices

Tags: networking, google-chrome, internet, ssl, protocol

In Chrome, I'm getting the dreaded ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when I visit some sites, two of which being Facebook and Instagram.  This is the case in browsers (Chrome, and similar error in Firefox) on both my phone and laptop.

I've tried the suggestions here https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/fix-err-ssl-protocol-error/ except for the ones involving accessing proxy settings from chrome because I get the same message like the one [here](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/run-chrome-chromium-proxy-settings-linux). Therefore I don't know how clear the SSL state, for example.  In lieu of this I deleted all chrome config files and reinstalled chrome.

Interestingly, both the Facebook messenger and Instagram apps were also unable to access their servers until I switched to using mobile data. On mobile data I could access Facebook through my phone's browser, but the apps started working as well. They continued to work after going back to using the WiFi.

Buoyed by this result, I tried loading Facebook while using my phone as a wifi hotspot.  I could then access Facebook.  Unfortunately, this time, the fix didn't persist when I went back onto the WiFi.

Long and short of it is that it's obviously something specific to my local network or my connection.  I've done a factory reset of the router and that hasn't helped.  The only thing I can think of that's even remotely unusual about my network is that I have a TVheadend server running on a Raspberry Pi.  Other than that I have my phone, my laptop and a smart tv on the same network.

I'm fresh out of ideas now, short of contacting TalkTalk to see if it's their problem.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  If it is TalkTalk's fault then it'd be useful to know so that I can threaten to cancel my contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TalkTalk routers very recently can go really crazy - Mine decided to not allow any exchange server connections, but allowed everything else - SSL connectivity too was hit and miss. Completely switch off parential controls / filters - These recently got added and are standard unless you choose to disable them - you need to do this with your talk-talk login on their site. They update the routers remotely with new definitions which sometimes causes the chaos.

I think you can apply for the VDSL login details via their helpdesk and purchase another router to get you out of trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been tearing my hair out over this.  Disabling the Kids Safe service solved it.